# How can I pass (save) a List from a View to a Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, save

I have a model like this:

```
public class TRViewModel
{
    public List<TR> TRecord { get; set; }
}

[Table("TRecord")]
public partial class TRecord
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("TID")]
    public int Tid { get; set; }
    public String Tname { get; set; }
}
```

The controller is like this:

```
    public ActionResult Audit(int? id)
    {
        var tQ = from t in db.TRecordDBSet
                        select t;

        var list = tQ.ToList();
        return View(list);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Audit(List<TRecord> list)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(list).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Audit");
        }
        return View(list);
    }
```

The view is like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tname)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <tr>
                    <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tid)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            @Html.EditFor(modelItem => item.Tname)
                    </td>
            </tr>
    }

<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to pass the list to the controller to save the new variable to the database but when debugging I found the list is `null`, what is going wrong?

Comment: Take a look at what is in your html. I suppose that all of your inputs from the collection have the same name. To bind multiple items into a collection you have to have them indexed with [1..n].

Comment: Try changing `foreach` to simple `for` loop and use index array for each model, e.g.: `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].Tid); Html.EditFor(modelItem => item[i].Tname) }`, or using more organized way by creating editor template with `EditorForModel`.

Comment: I think this link will be helpful for you. [how to pass list to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888248/submit-a-list-from-view-to-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have `IEnumerable<TRecord>` as model bound to view, you can change `foreach` loop to `for` loop with index array of every properties inside model and set binding type to `IList` to match with controller input parameter:

```
@model IList<TRecord>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // display names area

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].Tid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditFor(item => item[i].Tname)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    // submit button area
}
```

The other way to post `IEnumerable` collection is creating editor template and put HTML helpers inside it, then use `EditorForModel` (see Darin Dimitrov's approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037925/6378815)).

Similar issues:

[How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state)

[MVC passing IEnumerable<CustomVM> to Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742401/mvc-passing-ienumerablecustomvm-to-controller)

[Pass IEnumerable list to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299016/pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller)

Comment: Thank you  !!!! @Tetsuya Yamamoto

Comment: Thank you!!! Successed to save the list 

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].Tid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(item => item[i].Tname)
            </td>

I found that I must use EditorFor, that the values will pass to the list, it I use DisplayFor, the variable return to the list will changes to "null", how can I pass an original data to the controller without using EditorFor?

Comment: You can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item[i].Tid, new { @readonly = "readonly" })`. Note that `EditorFor` renders HTML input element depending on data type defined on model, and tid values should be passed as list input parameter.

Comment: that works and i don't want the box .....

Comment: only want the value to display

Comment: Since you only want to show value on `TextBoxFor`, use CSS style including `border: 0 none transparent`, e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item[i].Tid, new { @readonly = "readonly", @style = "border: 0 none transparent;" })`

Comment: may i shorten the width of the textbox?

Comment: Of course. Just add CSS width attribute by `new { @readonly = "readonly", @style = "border: 0 none transparent; width:[textbox size]" }`, or simply use a CSS class with `new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "[class name]" }` then putting all CSS selectors together inside that class.